# Looping over files in a directory and using the HEAD command

Tags: linux, bash, unix, scripting

Ok so I'm trying to get my script to loop over n amount of files in a directory, and make it so that the terminal prints 3-4 lines off the top of each file that has been looped.

Here's what I've got:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 for f in $1  #for the file in the directory (Specified by user)

 do

 head $2 $f    #Print the first n lines (Specified by user) of the file.

 done          #finish
```

Keep getting this as an error:
head: cannot open `3' for reading: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors in your script:

1) If you specify directory, you should loop through it's files by wildcard so change

```
    for f in $1
```

to

```
    for f in $1/*
```

2) Number of lines for `head` command is specified by `-n` flag, so change

```
    head $2 $f
```

to

```
    head -n $2 $f
```

Comment: Hi @Jakisa. Thanks for helping. I've changed the code as you suggested, but not the variable in $f is copying the value of $1 rather than taking the filename contained within the directory. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you run the script with
script_name directory_name number_of_lines
it should work. I've test it myself.
Actually, the effect you described happens if you have "for f in $1" and not "for f in $1/*" which is the reason why I wrote you to change it.